# how to pass parameters in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a search form like

```
<%= form_for(@blood_donor_form) do |f| %>


    Blood Group   <%= f.text_field :bloodGroup %>

    <%= link_to "Search", findBlood_path , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>

<% end %>
```

the controller looks like:

```
def findBlood
@blood_donor_form = BloodDonor.new 
@blood_donors = BloodDonor.find_all_by_bloodGroup("B+") 
end
```

so how to pass the value from the bloodGroup field to the controller ? Currently i hard coded it

Comment: @Vik you can use BloodDonor.find_all_by_bloodGroup("#{params[:bloodGroup]}") but your form needs to be submitted to the findBlood action so that the textfield parameter is passed to your findBlood action

Comment: right.. so that means <%= link_to "Search", findBlood_path , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%> wont work ? correcT? if yes then how should i submit the form to findBlood_path action?

Comment: @Vik if you need to 'submit' the the form to the findBlood action, then remove the link and write a button instead of it like this - "<%= f.submit, :class=>"btn btn-large btn-primary".

Comment: You do f.submit "search"

Comment: if i try to do <% f.submit "search %>  then it submits the form associated to blood_donor_form which is the model BloodDonor containing all the fields. And as a result it renders the complete form with errors on mandatory fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a form with the `form_for` helper or the `forn_tag` helper if you dont have a search model and get the search field in your controller with `params[:search]` or whatever you set up in the form.

Comment: sorry some post issues. its already there. i m not sure how to get value to the controller?